# how to get google authorization code

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, authorization, google-oauth, google-fusion-tables

Im using [Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/articles/oauthfusiontables) to get access token for my web application. but in the following steps:

1. Your web application redirects the user to Google Authorization page
2. User grants your web application access
3. Google redirects the user back to your web application and returns an authorization code

I dont know how to get this authorization code ? actually  in my python code I dont know how to get "auth_code"

```
data = urllib.urlencode({
'code': auth_code,
 'client_id': client_id,
  'client_secret': client_secret,
 'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
 'grant_type': 'authorization_code'
   })
```

Comment: you may try to start with this page instead: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution :) 
I should past this url in my browser and get the code

```
print '%s?client_id=%s&redirect_uri=%s&scope=%s&response_type=code' % \
   ('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth',
    clientID,
   redirect_uri,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/fusiontables')
```